# How to change the position of AngularJS floating button?

Tags: angularjs

I am using angujlarjs floating buttons.Initially my button was at bottom right.Now I want that button to be at top right.Inspite of changing position from br to tr,the button is still getting displayed at bottom right.

```
<ul class="mfb-component--br mfb-zoomin" data-mfb-state="closed" data-mfb-toggle="click"  menu-state="ctrl.menuState" toggling-method="click" ng-mouseleave="hovered()" ng-mouseenter="hovered()"  effect="zoomin" position="tl" mfb-menu="" >
<li class="mfb-component__wrap">
<a style="background:#7D7Df8;" class="mfb-component__button--main" ng-attr-data-mfb-label="{{label}}" ng-mouseleave="hovered()" ng-mouseenter="hovered()" ng-click="togglePannel()">
<i class="mfb-component__main-icon--resting ion-funnel"></i>
<i class="mfb-component__main-icon--active ion-close-round"></i>
</a>
<a style="background:#7D7Df8;"class="mfb-component__button--main" ng-attr-data-mfb-label="{{label}}" ng-mouseleave="hovered()" ng-mouseenter="hovered()" ng-click="show()">
<i class="mfb-component__main-icon--resting ion-plus-round"></i>
<i class="mfb-component__main-icon--active ion-close-round"></i>
</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.mfb-component--br` indicates that your button will be displayed on bottom-right. If this class is written by yourself then it's your fault. Remove this class from four `ul` and AngularJS should do the rest.